# Replace space digit " " to another

Tags: java, string, replace, space

I am looking for a solution concerning replacing space digits into another, for example:

```
"My Example is interesting".replaceAll(" ", "1");
```

does NOT return `"My1Example1is1interesting"`, but only `"My"`

I was looking for solutions also on StackOverflow, but usually found "Removing whitespaces from String/URL.." etc.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String in = s.next();
in = in.replaceAll("//s+", "1");
System.out.println(in);
```

Comment: Something else is going wrong in your code, so I suggest you post all of it, so we can see what's happening.  When I run `"My Example is interesting".replaceAll(" ", "1");`, it absolutely DOES return `"My1Example1is1interesting"`.

Comment: If you are doing same as mentioned in your question then it should work.String.replaceAll(" ","1"); is correct.

Comment: Deviation: your example is not interesting.

Comment: Your post is also far from being interesting :)

Comment: may be  String in = s.next(); this line causing problem.

Comment: @VasudevPathak not maybe, sure.

Comment: No it's just a fun reference to a [British radio Show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_a_Minute)

Comment: s.next(); reads till the first space. it just reading "my" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue is the way in which you are reading data. `Scanner.next()` reads only one word at a time. SO if your print the value which is read, it is actually `"My"`. use `nextLine()` to read the entire line.

print `in` and check what it prints. It should print `My` i.e, only one word and not *words separated by space*.

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks a lot!
Didn't know that this could be resposible for such inapropriate behaviour ;)

Comment: @Rafcik - as a thumb rule, always *print* and check what values you are getting from a file/ input stream (any IO source) if you are not sure about the APIs.

Comment: I just wrote this code for a test, I usually do not use Scanners, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remember that String object is immutable in Java, you should assign the result to a new String:

```
String res = "My Example is interesting".replaceAll(" ", "1");
```

Also note that because [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accepts a regex as the first parameter, you can improve the regex by having `\\s+` which will work on strings that have more than one or more spaces:

```
String res = "My   Example is     interesting".replaceAll("\\s+", "1");
```

---

Update: After you posted your code, the problem is not with `replaceAll`, you should use [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) instead of [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) because `next` reads only the first complete token.

Comment: @Rafcik Then we can't know what's the problem, maybe you're printing something else.. post your **full** code.

Comment: @VasudevPathak Replace `next` with `nextLine`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result to another variable.

```
 String s = "My Example is interesting";
 String result = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

This will remove spaces.

If you wan to replace with another text.

```
String result = s.replaceAll(" ", "My Text");
```